# Computable Functions

Tags: computability

I'm learning about computable functions. Our definition for computable function is as follows:

> Informally, a computable function is a function f : A → B such
> that there is a mechanical procedure for computing the result
> f(a) ∈ B for every a ∈ A.

they go on to give the following non-example:

> A function that takes an input p (which I assume to be a program), and checks if p is a syntactically valid Python program without any user interaction that terminates and returns 1 if this is true, 0 otherwise.

I was just trying to understand why this is not computable. I know when I write a program with incorrect syntax that I get an error when I try to run it, so I am assuming that it is possible to check whether a program is syntactically correct, but I have a hunch that the terminating part has to do with the halting problem. Is this simply just an obscured halting problem?

Comment: This is just the halting problem described in a slightly clumsy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "that terminates" is the halting problem, not really in disguise but also not pointed out as problematic.

Answer (score -3):

If $f:\Sigma^* \to \Sigma^*$ is function, and $\exists$ a Turing machine which on the input $w\in\Sigma^*$ writes $f(w)$, $\forall w\in\Sigma^*$, then we call $f$ as computable function. [What is a computable function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993807/what-is-a-computable-function)

To generalize the above notion of **computable function** as much as possible anything that applies an algorithm to an input deriving an output is a computable function even when applied by the human being "computers" of the film: "Hidden Figures".

> A function that takes an input p (which I assume to be a program), and
> checks if p is a syntactically valid Python program without any user
> interaction that terminates and returns 1 if this is true, 0
> otherwise.

The above function is computable for some inputs. Within the terms of the art of computer science a function is not computable unless it derives an output for all inputs in its domain.

**The above function can be transformed into an instance of the halting problem, thus is construed as not computable in this case.**

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: @Nathaniel It much more directly answers the question now.

Comment: Mixing ∃ and ∀ with English text doesn't really work IMO

Comment: @user253751 I am not mixing I am translating and generalizing.

Comment: Is there a reason why a program cannot check if a string is a valid Python program? (Don’t know Python well enough, for a specific C implementation I would see no problem).

Comment: @user253751 "Mixing ∃ and ∀ with English text doesn't really work" **The above is a verbatim quote from SE math.**